Vue3 + Typescript v-forでの'unknown'型を解決したい
<ul class="tabs">
    <li v-for="something in somethingList" :key="something.id" @click="change(something.id,something.text)" :class="{ 'isActive': isActive === something.id}">
      タブ{{ something.number }}
    </li>
  </ul>

上記コードのsomethingがunknown型になってしまいます。
somethingListは親コンポーネントでPropsとして渡しています。
defineProps({
  somethingList: Array,
  defoText: String
})

親側ではinterfaceを使っていますが、こちらとは関係ないんだろうなぁと思ってますが、どなたかご教示いただけませんか。

something は、どのように宣言されていますか？

Vue, v-for については詳しくないですが、Array のジェネリック型で解決できないでしょうか？
以下のように、配列内の要素の型を指定してやることで、v-for で展開されたときの要素の型を解決できないでしょうか？
defineProps({
  somethingList: Array<something>,
  defoText: String
})


記載いただいた感じでやったのですが、同じくエラーになってしまいました。ご教示頂きましてありがとうございます。もう少しジェネリックなども勉強してみます。

エラーメッセージを教えてもらえますか？
